How to offload CPU load to GPU in Unity physics simulations
I am trying to simulate some physics (developing robot controllers using NEAT algorithm) in Unity for my masters thesis, but I am being constrained by my CPU while my GPU is being left unused. Is it possible to offload some physics calculations onto my GPU?
Searching [unity-game-engine] [game-physics] gpu yields no relevant results on stackoverflow (nor does using [physics], nor [physics-engine])

Do you mean you have some random C# code that does custom physics calculations (separate from internal Unity physics computations), and you expect your own code to be magically run on GPU?

Did you read things like this ? https://forum.unity.com/threads/running-scripts-on-gpu-instead-of-cpu.325723/

@AlexeyS.Larionov no, I do no run custom physics calculations separate from internal Unity physics computations and expect them to magically run on GPU. I am asking if those internal Unity physics computations are parallelizable to the point of being runnable on a GPU. Or even, since I am currently running several instances that are entirely separate from one another, if an instance can be entirely off-loaded to the GPU, so I may use resources I have available, in spite of them being slower for serialized tasks

@BugFinder I am looking at what you sent, but unfortunately I worry that my lack of Unity experience is hitching me up. It looks like they are talking about shaders (Compute Shaders?), where I care only about the physics. Are you saying I should look further into CUDAs and OpenCLs work with Unity?

shaders is just the name for it, as the link explains, it is how to do a lot of small computations..

Strange naming convention; I'll have to take a look at how to apply shaders to calculate physics, then
